# How to remove cart item from the list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopping-cart

I have an error that complain my function is not defined within the scope of my document. I debugged and clear my cache, somehow i might miss something and need some help to fix this problem. Below is my code and  im using jquery to remove cart item from the list. The rest of other function works well. " Uncaught ReferenceError: removeItemFromCart is not defined
onclick".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-to-cart-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      var productId = $(this).data("id");
      console.log("Product ID:", productId);
      var productName = $(this).data("product-name");
      var productImage = $(this).data("product-image");

      var quantity = parseInt($("#quantity-input").val());
      //store the product ID in the session.
      var productImage = "img/" + productId + ".jpg";

      var productPrice = parseFloat($("#product-price-" + productId).text().replace("R", ""));
      var totalPrice = productPrice * quantity;

      //store the product details in the session.
      var cartItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [];
      cartItems.push({
          productId: productId,
          quantity: quantity,
          productImage: productImage,
          productName: productName
      });

      sessionStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add-to-cart.php",
      data: { productId: productId },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        updateCartBadge(); // Update the cart badge with the new count
        getCartItem(); // Refresh the cart items after adding
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("An error occurred while adding the item to the cart.");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });

    // Function to update cart badge.
    function updateCartBadge(userId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCartItemCount.php",
            data: { userId: userId},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('Cart Item Count:', response);
        $("#cart-badge").text(response); // Update the cart badge count
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("An error occurred while retrieving the cart item count.");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}

// Function to update cart items in the modal
function updateCartItems(cartData) {
    var cartItems = cartData.cartItems;
    var cartContainer = $("#cart-items");

    // Clear the previous content
    cartContainer.empty();

    // Loop through the cart items and add them to the HTML
    cartItems.forEach(function (item) {
        var totalPrice = item.totalPrice || 0; // Ensure totalPrice is a valid number or set it to 0
        var cartItemHtml = `
            <tr>
                <td>${item.product_name}</td>
                <td><img src="${item.product_image}" 
               alt="${item.product_name}" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
                <td>R${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>${item.quantity}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
                data-productId="${item.product_id}" 
                onclick="removeItemFromCart(${item.product_id})">Remove
                </button></td>

            </tr>
        `;

        // Append the cart item HTML to the container
        cartContainer.append(cartItemHtml);
    });

    // Update the total price
    var totalPriceContainer = $("#total-price");
    totalPriceContainer.text("Total Price: R" + cartData.totalPrice.toFixed(2));
}

// Use event delegation to handle click events for 
// "Remove" buttons inside the modal
$("#cartModal").on("click", ".remove-cart-item", function () {
    var productId = $(this).data("productId");
    removeItemFromCart(productId);
});

//removing item from cart.
    function removeItemFromCart(productId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "removeCartItem.php",
        data: { productId: productId }, // Include the product ID in the data
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // Item removed successfully, update the cart display
                getCartItemsForModal();
                updateCartItems();
            } else {
                alert(response.message); // Display the error message from the server
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("An error occurred while removing the item from the cart.");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
    });
}

    // Call the backend to fetch cart data when the cart modal is opened
    $("#cartModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCartData.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (cartData) {
                console.log("Response from the server:", cartData);
                updateCartItems(cartData);
                updateCartBadge();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("An error occurred while fetching cart item details");
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });    
    
    // function to populate the cart modal with cart items.
    function getCartItemsForModal() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCartItem.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#cart-items").html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("An error occured while retrieving cart items");
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },

        });
    }
    updateCartItems();
    //call getCartItemsForModal function.
    $("#cart-badge-btn").click(function () {
        getCartItemsForModal();
    });

    
// function to get item from the cart.
  function getCartItem() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "getCartItem.php",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#cart-items").html(response); // Update the cart items on the page
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("An error occurred while retrieving the cart items.");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  }

  // Call updateCartBadge and getCartItem on page load
  updateCartBadge();
  getCartItem();
});
```

Comment: Why not get rid of the inline onclick, add the class of `.remove-cart-item` to that button and change your modal delegation to delegate it to the document instead `$(document).on("click", ".remove-cart-item", function () {`? That will allow your modal button and the other buttons to use the same delegated click handler

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you must ensure that the removeItemFromCart function is defined in your HTML before it is referenced. Moving the function definition to the top of your code will solve the problem

Comment: i am using html on the function itself, see var cartHtml = ..... and its defined inside and also tried to use delegate, still no luck, clear cache and try again.